# Converting array of an object passed in as an argument to vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to convert an array of Wall to a vector of Wall. The array is passed in as an argument and within the function I am trying to convert it using the `insert()`. I receive an error saying that *"no instance of overloaded function "std::begin" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (Wall *)"*

```
int func(int row, int col, Wall walls[]) {
  // Some code before ...

  // Converting array of Wall to vector
  std::vector<Wall> vecWalls;
  vecWalls.insert(vecWalls.begin(), std::begin(walls), std::end(walls));
 }
```

I have tried just creating another array of Wall within the function and using that to as an argument for the `insert()`. However, that did not create any issues.

```
Wall walls2[5];
std::vector<Wall> vecWalls;
vecWalls.insert(vecWalls.begin(), std::begin(walls2), std::end(walls2));
```

What is happening to my array of Wall when it is being passed as an argument.

Comment: It decays to a pointer. Just use `std::vector` all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `Wall walls[]` will decay to `Wall *walls`. Since you lose the length information you will need to pass the number of elements in that array along as parameter. Like this:

```
int func(int row, int col, Wall* walls, int len) {
    std::vector<Wall> vecWalls;
    vecWalls.insert(vecWalls.begin(), walls, walls + len);

    //or shorter:
    std::vector<Wall> vecWalls2(walls, walls + len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple C array doesn't know anything about iterators, but you can fill std::vector using simple pointers on first and next after last array items.

```
int func(Wall* walls, size_t arraySize)
{
    std::vector<Wall> vecWalls;
    vecWalls.insert(vecWalls.begin(), &walls[0], &walls[arraySize]);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Wall walls[10] = {};
    // Fill walls array

    const size_t arraySize = sizeof(walls) / sizeof(walls[0]);
    func(walls, arraySize);
}
```

Moreover, if you create new vector you can initialize it with items from you simple array like this:

```
std::vector<Wall> vecWalls2(&walls[0], &walls[arraySize]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard functions `std::begin` and `std::end` may not be used with pointers as their arguments.

In the function declaration

```
int func(int row, int col, Wall walls[]) {
```

the parameter `Wall walls[]` is adjusted by the compiler to pointer type `Wall *walls` and the passed to the function array also is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

I suppose that within the function the array pointed to by walls is not changed.

In this case the function can be defined the following way

```
int func( int row, int col, const Wall walls[], size_t n ) {
  // Some code before ...

  // Converting array of Wall to vector
  std::vector<Wall> vecWalls( walls, walls + n );
 }
```